# NameError: при написании игры на Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, gui, pygame

Пишу учебный проект при помощи *Pygame*, по учебнику *Э.Мэтиз "Изучаем *Python*"* . 
При определении одной из переменных `screen` вылезает ошибка:

> `NameError: ...`.

Хотя переменная инициализирована.

Не вижу своей ошибки.
Буду рад помощи.

**main.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion():
    """A class for managing resources and game behavior"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Inizialization game and create games resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(screen)

    def run_game(self):
        """Launch main cycle game"""
        while True:
            # keyboard and mouse
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            # Display the last drawn screen
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create exemple and launch game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

**ship.py**

```
import pygame


class Ship():
    """Class for control ship"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initialization ship and sets its initial position"""

        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
        #Load image ship
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Each new ship appears at the bottom of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw ship in current position"""

        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

---

Текст сообщения об ошибке:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Gradysnik\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\game.py", line 33, in 
> ai = AlienInvasion()
> File "C:\Users\Gradysnik\Desktop\python_work\alien_invasion\game.py", line 15, in **init**
> self.ship = Ship(screen)
> NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

---

---

**Update**.

**settings.py**:

```
class Settings():
    """A class for save all settings game Alien Invasion"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Inicialization settings game"""

        # Display settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Comment: `self.screen`??

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `settings.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я отметил строки, в которые внес изменения.

**game.py**

```
import  sys                                                                 # +++
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion():
    """A class for managing resources and game behavior"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Inizialization game and create games resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self.screen)                                       # + self.

    def run_game(self):
        """Launch main cycle game"""
        while True:
            # keyboard and mouse
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            # Display the last drawn screen
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create exemple and launch game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

**ship.py**

```
import pygame                                                            # +++

class Ship():
    """Class for control ship"""
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initialization ship and sets its initial position"""
        self.screen = ai_game                                             #.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.get_rect()                             #ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        #Load image ship
#        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')   
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Ok.png')
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #Each new ship appears at the bottom of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw ship in current position"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**settings.py**

```
class Settings():
    """A class for save all settings game Alien Invasion"""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Inicialization settings game"""
        # Display settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]